# NSMutableString is null after appending

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to build an array of strings which will be added to an XML soap request.

I have a simple loop to build the array:

MarcTagsList is an NSArray of strings which contains the values ["82a","100a","245b","520a"] and is passed as a parameter.

```
NSMutableString *xmlTagList;

for(i=0; i<numberOfTags; i++)
{
   [xmlTagList appendFormat:@"<string>%@</string>",MarcTagList[i]];
   NSLog(@" appending - <string>%@</string>",MarcTagList[i]);

}
```

The log output shows the loop and MarcTag values are OK, however when the loop is complete

```
NSLog(@"xmlTagList %@", xmlTagList);
```

Shows xmlTagList to be null.

Comment: So, where did you create the mutable string in the first place?

Comment: Where is the line: `xmlTagList = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]`?

Comment: NSMutableString *xmlTagList = [NSMutableString new];

Comment: If you ran your code in the debugger, you'd have seen that xmlTagList was nil.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableString from folder contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500609/nsmutablestring-from-folder-contents)

Comment: allocate the instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly `intialize` `xmlTagList` string

```
//allocated
NSMutableString *xmlTagList=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

#### OR

```
//auto-referenced
NSMutableString *xmlTagList=[NSMutableString string];
```

#### OR

```
//auto-referenced
NSMutableString *xmlTagList=[NSMutableString new];
```

#### OR

```
//auto-referenced
NSMutableString *xmlTagList= @"";
```

Now use `xmlTagList` for further requirement ie append operation

```
for(i=0; i<numberOfTags; i++)
{
   [xmlTagList appendFormat:@"<string>%@</string>",MarcTagList[i]];
   NSLog(@" appending - <string>%@</string>",MarcTagList[i]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies ... yeah I didn't initialize the string...I'm new to objective-c

Comment: @HotLicks Again you act aggressively to other people ? can't you finally grow up and have some manners ? be nice to other people. not everybody are code monkeys, people have life beyond coding,maybe this is why they have manners and you dont. shame on you .

Comment: @Curnelious - Shame on me for explaining that someone should not start programming in Objective-C until they have some general programming experience?  It's a disservice to the individual to not explain this.

Comment: @HotLicks - I am not familiar with objective c syntax and have been given a work task that must be completed , so rather than struggle alone I choose ask some questions here. after all that's what stackoverflow is for isnt it ? ... about getting/giving technical help and NOT voicing opinions on someones abilities

Comment: @user1882582 - Outside of the call syntax and a few other oddities it's plain old C (not even C++) syntax.  Pointers work essentially the same way they do in C.  You can't reference using a pointer until the pointer is assigned a value.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
NSMutableString *xmlTagList;
```

to:

```
NSMutableString *xmlTagList = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
```